# Secure an Azure app service (REST API) using Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a simple requirement of securing an Azure App Service (REST API) such that - There is no anonymous access to the API and only selected clients (App registration client ids) can access the API using token based authentication/authorization.

I have done the following -

1. Create an app registration for the service (REST API).
2. Create a default scope for the above app registration
   (api://svcguid/.default)
3. Create an app registration for the
           client.
4. Add the client in the service app registration page >  "Expose an API" page > Authorized client applications section.
5. Wire the app registrations in the API and client code/configuration

The issue with the above approach is that any new client (in the same AD tenant) which is not added to "Authorized client applications" sections in point 4, is also able to access the API.
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's controlled by an administrator action to grant the client(s) access to the API scope in the Azure Portal, as in [step 6](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) of my write up.

The API can also explicitly check for this scope when it validates access tokens.